# Defining drop-down menu style in CSS for a Joomla template

Tags: php, html, css, joomla, joomla3.0

I am trying to build a custom template from scratch for my Joomla 3.9 website. I am new to web design. I have been following several tutorials on how to set up menu style via CSS, but I cannot seem to find information on how to define the drop-down menu style. The menu items are defined in Joomla configuration, and the menu should be injected into the right place.

relevant lines from index.php:

```
<body> 
 <div class="nav">
    <nav>
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="navigation" style="none"/>
    </nav>
 </div>
</body>
```

And from template.css:

```
.nav {
  background-color:#FFA500;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}


ul.nav { //this element needs centering
  margin:auto;
  width:80%;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #FFA500;
}

ul.nav li {
  float:left;
  display:block;;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-right: 3px solid #bbb;
}

ul.nav li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}


ul.nav li a{
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px
}

ul.nav li:hover {
  background-color: #e09100;
}
```

This code works fine for displaying the menu the way I want (except for not centering it in the screen, but that's not relevant) for simple menu items. However, if I add sub-menu items in Joomla Menu configuration, it gets all messed up. I want these sub-menus to be displayed in a drop-down fashion when the user hovers over the parent item with the mouse, but instead, right now these sub-menus are displayed below the parent item statically. Obviously, that's because I haven't written the code for that part yet.
Problem is, I do not know how to define the style for these sub-menu items, because they are not defined in the CSS, but instead, provided by Joomla. I cannot find any relevant documentation that would tell me the keywords to hook up to these items. Can someone tell me how to turn these sub-menu items into a nice drop-down menu when the user hovers the mouse over the parent menu item?

Comment: I'm not sure if trying to do this with CSS is very hard or just madness. Usually we just use JavaScript to get the positioning right. Maybe it's wise to start with a more approachable solution.

Comment: @Halcyon - I'm a sucker for pure CSS solutions whenever possible, and positioning submenus can be done easily if you set position:relative on the parent LI

Comment: Justinas can you please provide the HTML that the jdoc:include line renders, that will make it much easier to diagnose and provide an accurate solution for you

Comment: James, could you please tell me where I can find that HTML? Sorry, I've been doing this only for a few days, and there's a lot of basic stuff that I still don't know.

Comment: You may like to post your question at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange to see if you can get some satisfaction there. If you post, please include a screenshot of what you are currently getting and perhaps scribble on the image to show what you desire.